# JQuery Progress Bar IE 10 not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

When my form is submitted I have a JQuery progress bar that toggles. It works in FireFox, Chrome and IE 11 but it isn't working in IE 10. It just shows a gray bar. Any suggestions to get it going in IE 10?

**JQuery**

```
//toggle visibility of status bar 
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    if ($("#frm").valid()) {
        var progBar = $("#progressbar").progressbar({value:false});
        $(progBar).toggle();
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
<div id="progressbar" style="display:none">
</div>
```